# Do different sections of candy corn taste different?

Tags: nutrition

[Brach's candy corn](https://www.brachs.com/products/others/candy-corn.html) is a popular confectionery in the USA around Halloween. It has three stripes of color.

Some people claim that all three sections taste different:

e.g. [Thrillist](https://www.thrillist.com/eat/nation/halloween-candy-do-the-sections-of-candy-corn-taste-different-from-one-another) conducted an informal blind-taste test:

> The Verdict
>
> Well, three of our four tasters seemed to find at least some differences in the taste of the sections. [...]

Some people deny it:

e.g. [Vox.com](https://www.vox.com/2015/10/29/9633560/candy-corn-explained):

> Though some have conducted taste tests that claim otherwise, candy corn is made of the same ingredients all the way through, so the three sections taste identical.

Do the different sections have different tastes?

Comment: Even if you can taste a difference, that doesn’t mean that it’s not just food coloring. I remember reading that some people can taste/feel the difference between certain food colorings, but this was about another type of candy (M&Ms maybe).

Comment: There is also a difference between "same ingredients" and "tastes the same". Bread and toast are made of the same ingredients.

Answer (score 4):

There is a 30 October 2013 article [Go Inside The Factory That Makes 2 Billion Candy Corn Kernels Every Year](https://www.businessinsider.com/see-how-candy-corn-gets-made-2013-10) that is based upon the History Channel's video footage.  "The History Channel visited the Brach's candy plant in a recent episode of 'Modern Marvels' ".

The article links to the video and has stills from the video.

Different dyes are added to the same initial mixture of other ingredients.

Comment: So your answer to the question in the title is "No" then, correct?  Or do they dyes add flavor?

Answer (score 1):

[From this video](https://youtu.be/HHFyVozbutA?t=66) you can see that the ingredients for each part are only different in the color, which although may be inadvertently tasted by some people, is not intended to effect a different flavor.